# Replace characters from one string with the characters from another

Tags: android

I am trying to swap out characters from one string to those in another (like the simple alphabetic offset code people used as kids), the code I am using is

```
   public void convertMe(){
        //lets convert the text 
        rInput = etrInput.getText().toString();

        //lets extract the input characters to a chararray
        char[] inputArray = rInput.toCharArray();

        //lets get the numbers and make them a string
        rNumbers = etrNumbers.getText().toString();

        //lets extract them and place them in an chararray
        char[] numbersArray = rNumbers.toCharArray();

     for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
     rResult = rNumbers.replace(numbersArray[i], inputArray[i]);
     }

    }
```

When I run the code I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, but I dont really understand why that is happening (since the loop I am running is within the array bounds from inputArray.length).

EDIT2:

Clarification of the behaviour of my code above:
If the string rInput is smaller than the rNumbers array then the app crashes.  If not then the only character that is encoded is the last character looped through the array.

I would like to be able to 'encode' all characters in the array, and also be able to encode any number of characters, not be limited to matching the length of the numbersArray.

EDIT1:  I had missed the fact that the arrays are not the same length.  So rephrasing the question:

How can I deal with the arrays of different lengths to substitute the values?

rInput must be 10character word
rNumbers can be any length string but only containing numbers.

The result should be that the numbers are "coded" in simple terms using the letters from the rInput charArray:

```
ACHROMATIC
0123456789
```

So encoding 5501 should give the answer MMAC, or 5512345 should give MMCHROM.

Edit:
Try and improve my description:

User enters a 10character word with no 2 characters the same (like the example achromatic)

User can then enter a series of numbers.  (5501)

The substitution should then take the int value of each digit entered by the user,  look up that value from the first word and substitute that character:

The fifth letter in the word achromatic is m (assuming you count from 0). The result of 5501 being substituted should be MMAC.

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: My guess is `numbersArray` is shorter than `inputArray`. Since you are looping using `inputArray`'s length, if `numberArray`'s length is shorter you access an invalid position, leading to a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`.

Comment: Try to print the length of 2 arrays and compare..

Comment: `inputArray` might have a greater size than `numbersArray`, In that case `numbersArray[i]` might be out of range.

Comment: Thanks, your right, they are different lengths... Question has been edited to reflect the follow on question

Comment: Is anyone able to help me get this code working please?

Answer (score 2):

is your `numbersArray` shorter than your `inputArray`?

To prevent this error:

```
 for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
     if(i>= numbersArray.length){
     // Log exception
     return;
     }
 rResult = rNumbers.replace(numbersArray[i], inputArray[i]);
 }
```

//Edited based on your questionchange:
It look like you wan't to implement a caesar chiffre, i would realize this with a HashMap of Chars, have a look at the following pseudocode:

```
// prepare the engine
// ctor
HashMap<char,char> dictionary = new HashMap<char,char>;
     for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
         if(i>= numbersArray.length){
         // Log exception
         return;
         }
     dictionary.put(numbersArray[i], inputArray[i]);
     }

// do the magic
public String encrypt(String input){
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
input.setCharAt(i,dictionary.get(input[i]
}
```

You'll find copy paste ready implementation on google.

EDIT2:
I hope i've understand what you meant.
On the fly implementation

```
public String convertMe(String encode){
    //lets convert the text 
 String   rInput = "ACHROMATIC";

//lets extract the input characters to a chararray
char[] inputArray = rInput.toCharArray();

    //lets get the numbers and make them a string
   String rNumbers = "0123456789" ;

//lets extract them and place them in an chararray
char[] numbersArray = rNumbers.toCharArray();

 for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
     encode = encode.replace(numbersArray[i], inputArray[i]);
 }

 return encode;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,  but I think I want a simple substitution cipher rather than the ceased.  I have updated my question to give an example of my expected output.  I am still struggling to see how to implement the substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the update,  but I'm am not sure I described what I want to achieve well.  I will edit the question again.

Comment: Thanks for the update,  but I'm am not sure I described what I want to achieve well.  I will edit the question again.

Comment: I have tried your update but it behaves the same as my code in the original question.  If the string rNumbers is smaller than the rInput array then the app crashes.  If not then the only character that is encoded is the last character looped through the array